# Binding ViewModel property to the primary View or sub view if primary view including sub view?

Tags: xaml, silverlight, mvvm

I have a primary View. It includes FirstSubView and SecondSubView.

```
<navigation:Page x:Class="Test.Views.PreimaryView" 
       xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" 
       xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" 
       xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
       xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
       xmlns:localViews="clr-namespace:Test.Views"
       mc:Ignorable="d"
       xmlns:navigation="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Controls;assembly=System.Windows.Controls.Navigation"
       d:DesignWidth="1057" d:DesignHeight="707"
       Title="TestView Page">
<UserControl.Resources>
    <silverlightLib:BooleanVisibilityConverter x:Key="BooleanVisibilityConverter"></silverlightLib:BooleanVisibilityConverter>
</UserControl.Resources>
<ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" Background="Transparent">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
            <localViews:FirstSubView DataContext="{Binding VmFirst, Mode=TwoWay}"></localViews:FirstSubView>
            <localViews:SecondSubView DataContext="{Binding VmSecond, Mode=TwoWay}" Visibility="{Binding IsAdjustVisible, Converter={StaticResource BooleanVisibilityConverter}}"></localViews:SecondSubView>
        </StackPanel>
    </StackPanel>
</ScrollViewer>
```

You see in the SecondSubView I have a binding property `IsAdjustVisible`.

My question is where an I set it? I set up it in both ViewModels to adjust the visibility of the second View. But it doesn't work, even when it is false, the View is still shown.

Comment: Try Like this. `<Grid><Grid.DataContext><local:VmSecond></Grid.DataContext><localViews:SecondSubView Visibility="{Binding IsAdjustVisible, Converter={StaticResource BooleanVisibilityConverter}}"></localViews:SecondSubView></Grid>`

Comment: @AVKNaidu, there is a similar [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4893904/adjust-the-visibility-property-of-a-view-not-working). I tried it but it is just not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found the issue. I only need one place to put the properties. Which is the sub-View rather than the Main View.